# How to right-align a title (without creating a complete custom title page)?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titles

I suppose this is a simple matter, but I'm still finding my way around where to put things in LaTeX.

I would like to right-align (i.e. flush to right) the contents of an article's title page. By default it's centered. My preamble (leaving out other stuff) is basic:

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}
\title{My Title}
\author{This is me}
\date{Aug 2010}
```

I read in the LaTeX wikibook (wonderful resource) that one way to do that is to create a custom title within

```
\begin{titlepage} ... 
\begin{flushright}
% title elements here
\end{flushright}
\end{titlepage}.
```

But this is a heavy-handed solution and I hope there is a simpler way.

Thank you.

Comment: I *thought* I had an answer for you, but it ran into trouble. You might want to look at any answers to [the question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1255/why-does-author-respond-differently-to-hfill-than-do-date-and-title-in-maket) I asked about it.

Comment: I don't thing your solution _is_ heavy-handed. The standard `\maketitle` macro was meant to provide a rather inflexible way to produce titles, and the `titlepage` environment is intended exactly for what you want to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A dirty solution would be:

```
\begingroup
\let\center\flushright
\let\endcenter\endflushright
\maketitle
\endgroup
```

Then it would be right aligned, the author, as it is in a table, not quite. Here you can just define the author like this: `\author{This is me\hspace*{-\tabcolsep}}`.

But I personally would use the `titling` package, as frabjous already suggested.

Comment: Dirty hack, but indeed gets the job done! Although I wouldn't recommend going around and writing this for every new document, as a one-off hack I really like it!

Comment: interesting hack, it works indeed :)

Comment: I really like it as a hack; rather than rewriting the code for the titlepage you change its meaning.  IMO this is dirty and clean at the same time (dirty because the original code has a different meaning than it'll seem to have, looking at it, but clean because you're not copy-pasting/rewriting its functionality).  Kudos!

Answer (score 15):

I’m not sure this is really “easier”, but how about something like:

```
\usepackage{titling}
\pretitle{\begin{flushright}\LARGE}
\posttitle{\par\end{flushright}\vskip 0.5em}
\preauthor{\begin{flushright}\large \lineskip 0.5em}
\postauthor{\par\end{flushright}}
\predate{\begin{flushright}\large}
\postdate{\par\end{flushright}}
```

along with the regular \maketitle command?

See the [titling package](http://ctan.org/pkg/titling) documentation for more info.

(Otherwise you’ll need to switch to a class that has its own mechanism for this, like memoir or KOMA script article.)

Comment: a vote up for referencing the 'titling' package which I didn't know about.