# Why does \author respond differently to \hfill than do \date and \title in \maketitle?

Tags: titles

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1254/how-to-right-align-a-title-without-creating-a-complete-custom-title-page) asks how to align titlepage elements to the right. I was trying out a possible an answer to it when to my surprise, my solution *almost* worked. (I was expecting success or abject failure.) The code

```
document\documentclass[notitlepage]{article}
\title{\hfill{}Title}
\author{\hfill{}Author}
\date{\hfill{}Date}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

sets the title and date flush right as I'd hoped. However, 'Author' is set centred, as though I'd not put in the `\hfill` at all. This surprised me---I'd have expected my idea to work for all three fields of the title page or none.

Why does `\author` behave differently in conjunction with `\hfill` in `\maketitle` than do `\title` and `\date`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default \maketitle command puts the author field inside a centered tabular environment, but not the title or date. Don’t ask me why. You can customize the command with the titling package. See [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1254/how-to-right-align-a-title-without-creating-a-complete-custom-title-page) for info on using it to right-align a title.

Comment: Well, that's odd. Thanks. (The question that you linked to is the one that caused me to stumble on the behaviour---I linked to it in my question.)

Comment: Tabular environment? Eewww- that's like table-based design on websites

Comment: Well, its the best way to get the layout that the standard author field results in

Comment: In the argument of \author, two ore more authors are separated by the \and command - therefore the use the tabular environment. (Although there may be better solutions to acchieve the desired layout.)