# How to add the author to the right mailbox？

Tags: xetex

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{ctexart}
\title {title}
\author{author}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Author is in the center，but I hope it can be on the right.

Comment: Welcome. Please see if the answers at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1254/how-to-right-align-a-title-without-creating-a-complete-custom-title-page could help.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{ctexart}
\usepackage{titling}
\preauthor{\begin{flushright}\large \lineskip 0.5em}
\postauthor{\par\end{flushright}}
\title{title}
\author{author}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @ChenEric, you are welcome.